# Custom reusable react component to show or Hide child elements based on flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

trying to create a custom component to show or hide child elements using react but didn't get any reference on my requirement and finally ended up with SO. I want to create a simple component to show or hide the child elements as shown in the below way.

```
<Authorize isAuthorized={true} >
<div>
   Welcome User
</div>
</Authorize>
```

Comment: The render function of the component `Authorize` must be something like `if(props.isAuthorized) {return props.children} else {return null;}`

Answer (score 2):

So you're looking to take advantage of the `children` prop:

```
const Authorize = props => {
  if (props.isAuthorized) {
    return props.children;
  }
  // Return non-authorized content/warning
  return "You are not authorized";
}
```

Now you can use the component as you intended:

```
<Authorize isAuthorized={true}>
  <div>
    Welcome User
  </div>
</Authorize>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import React from 'react';
export const Authorized = ({isAuth, children}) => {
   return isAuth ? <>{children}</>: <h1>not allowed...</h1>;
}
```